# Always show overlay for edges in Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, overlay, cytoscape.js

Is there a way to always show the edge line overlay in Cytoscape.js

The gif below show that the overlay is shown when the edge is active (after select or tap)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScDQa.jpg]

Here is the current styling I have :

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
        .selector('node')
        .css({
            'background-color': '#69B8B6',
            'border-color': '#AABFB8',
            'border-width': '2px',
            'width': '35px',
            'height': '35px',
            'content': 'data(name)',
            'font-size': '11px',
            'font-weight': 'bold',
            'color': '#337AB7'
        })
        .selector('edge')
        .css({
            'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
            'source-arrow-shape': 'circle',
            'curve-style': 'bezier',
            //'control-point-weight': 0.5,
            'content': 'data(name)',
            'font-size': '7px',
            'line-color': '#E4860D',
            'line-style': 'dotted',
            'overlay-color': '#c0c0c0',
            'overlay-padding': '50px',
            'overlay-opacity': 100
        })
        .selector('node:selected')
        .css({
            'background-color': '#E4860D'
        })
        .selector(':active')
        .css({
            'line-color': '#E4860D',
            'line-style': 'solid',
            'overlay-color': '#c0c0c0',
            //'overlay-padding': '100px',
            'overlay-opacity': 100
        }),
    layout: {
        name: 'grid',
        padding: 10
    },
    userZoomingEnabled: false,
    ready: function(){ console.log('ready') }
});
```

However this has no effect of the edge overlay for non active states.

Comment: You can see how the edge drawing works in https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/v2.3.8/src/extensions/renderer.canvas.drawing-edges.js

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this, as far as I can see I have to specify overlay colors right ? it seems like this overlay only appears when I select the edge.

Comment: I don't know what would be the answer, neither how should the HTML5  canvas rendering code look like, neither what you really mean by the "shadow". I just know where to put the breakpoints. If you're looking for a way to specify edge's opacity and thickness then this question may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928151/increase-width-of-selected-edges-only-cytoscape-js

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I edited the question and added an animated gif link to show the effect I desire.

Comment: argh and this one ? http://imgur.com/MoumiYW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [`overlay-*`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/overlay) properties with whatever selector you want in your stylesheet (probably just `edge` in your case).

Comment: I m failing to implant this.... can anyone give some fiddle. or example

Comment: I want to show overlay as long as a node is selected. I tried this        
"selector": "node:selected",
      "style": {
        "overlay-color": "red"
      }                                                                                                                                  overlay disappears after "activity" is gone. My ultimate goal it to make an effect which does not affects the nodes' original properties like color, shape, size etc... like this https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DuY9pY4WsAULxyD.jpg:large

Comment: Don't skip properties if you're not sure what the default values are.  In general, you should specify every property explicitly if it's important to your app, just as you would for css in the dom.